# Merging PDF files in Haskell

Tags: haskell, pdf-generation

The Preview application on the Mac allows one to merge multiple PDF files, although the functionality is rather obscure. I'm writing a utility in Haskell that needs to perform a similar task, that is, merge an arbitrary number of PDF files into one new file.

Does anyone have a suggestion as to where to start with this? Obviously if there's a library on Hackage that will do most of the work out of the box that would be ideal, but if not, then some pointers about where to start would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I'm working on [pdf library](https://github.com/Yuras/pdf-toolbox), that supports parsing and generating. It is low level, higher level tools are in todo list yet (because it is hard to design good high level API).

[Here](https://github.com/Yuras/pdf-toolbox/blob/master/examples/unpack-and-decrypt-pdf-file.hs) is an example of unpacking and decrypting of PDF file. It is easy to implement PDF merging, but you need to be familiar with PDF internals.

ADDED:
I create a [basic example](https://github.com/Yuras/pdf-toolbox/blob/master/examples/merge-pdf-files.hs) of merging PDF files in Haskell. 150 lines of code total, but it lacks few features (see comments at on the top of the file). They are easy to add, so let me know if you are interested.

Comment: Thanks Yuras, that's brilliant. I'll have a go at implementing my features using your library and let you know how I get on.

Answer (score 2):

The PDF file format isn't that complicated. Adobe has an official specification document for it somewhere. Essentially a PDF file contains a set of numbered "objects". You'd have to get all the objects from each PDF file, renumber them so they're unique, and then you need to fiddle with the page index so all the pages actually show up.

There appear to be a couple of packages on Hackage for *writing* PDF files, but I don't see much for *reading* them. You may like to look at the source code for `pdfsplit` for ideas. Also `HPDF`.

Comment: Also, if you just need help on how to go about merging PDF files, there's a Java program called [PDFtk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) whose code (GPL) might help you.

Comment: @DonStewart AFAIK it doesn't support encryption, xref streams and compressed objects. Right now in my `~/Download` folder ~50% of PDF files can't be parsed by the library.It renders it unusable.

Comment: As author of `pdfsplit`, I can guess that you'll be disappointed when you look at the internals: it does nothing but shell out to LaTeX. Of course, if that's on option, it's a great one; no sense using the wrong tool (in this case, Haskell, I'm afraid) for the job!